# How can i remove a json array from JSON

Tags: jquery

when i click on Addons , it opens a popup button where i can select / unselect checkboxes , i am updating this data to the data-stuff which is a data - attr .

The data inside data-stuff data-array looks this way

```
[
    {
        "name": "checkbox-mini-0",
        "cost": "20"
    },
    [
        {
            "name": "checkbox-mini-1",
            "cost": "10"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "checkbox-mini-4",
            "cost": "199"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "checkbox-mini-5",
            "cost": "233"
        }
    ]
]
```

my question is When i uncheck , how can i remove the array based on the name ??

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
// checkbox checked
//var toppcrusts = [];
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event) {
    var vendoritemsdata = $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff');

    var checkboxid = $(this).next().attr("id");
    var cost = $(this).attr("cost");

    var toppcrusts = {
        'name': checkboxid,
        'cost': cost
    };
    vendoritemsdata.push(toppcrusts);
    $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff', vendoritemsdata).attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(vendoritemsdata));
});

// checkbox Unchecked
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event) {
    var vendoritemsdata = $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff');

    var name = $(this).next().attr("id");;
    $.each(vendoritemsdata, function ( i, item) {
        if(item.name == name){
            vendoritemsdata.splice(i, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff', vendoritemsdata).attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(vendoritemsdata));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lf9q56hw/)

Note: the `.attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(vendoritemsdata))` is not really required... it is done just because in your sample you are updating the attribute, instead of using attribute use the data api

Also there is a slight change in the data structure as I think the array of array is not really required.

Comment: Thank you so much , but i want to remove only the specific array that is  unchecked element from the data -array . (At present it is removing the last one present inside the data-array)

Comment: @Kiran yesterday you had a similar question to update the attribute value... why was it... that is not really required... as I have done in this fiddle